# CSS text div ignoring header and menu divs in FireFox

Tags: firefox, html, overlap

Everything was looking fine in IE, Chrome, iOS, and Android, but my brother-in-law just informed me the page is acting up in FireFox. I installed FF to test, and this is what I saw:

http://www.sourceplumbing.com/images/ffscreenshot.jpg

And this is how it should look (and does in the other browsers):

http://www.sourceplumbing.com/images/iescreenshot.jpg

I would appreciate any help figuring this one out. Why does the text cut through the previous DIV's in FF, but not other browsers? Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">

    <div id="header">
      <a href="/"><img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png" alt="Source Plumbing Home"></a>
      <img id="servingsince" src="/images/servingsince.png" alt="Serving Since 1997">
    </div>
    <div id="phone">
      <a href="tel:1-949-632-5995"><img src="/images/phone-fax-number.png" alt="Click here from your mobile phone to call us now." title="Click here form your mobile phone to call us now."></a>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/leak-detection.html">Leak Detection</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leak Repairs</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/reroute.html">Leak Rerouting</a></li>
            <li><a href="/repipe.html">Complete Repipe</a></li>
            <li><a href="/drywall-repair.html">Drywall Repair</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Water Heaters</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/traditional-water-heater.html">Traditional Water Heaters</a></li>
            <li><a href="/tankless-water-heater.html">Tankless Units</a></li>
            <li><a href="/hybrid-water-heater.html">Hybrid Systems</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Plumbing Fixtures</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/fixtures-faucet.html">Kitchen & Bathroom Faucets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/fixtures-toilet.html">Toilet Installs & Upgrades</a></li>
            <li><a href="/fixtures-shower.html">Shower Fixtures</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/reviews.html">Customer Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="/social-media.html">Social Media</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.angieslist.com/companylist/us/ca/laguna-niguel/christensen-plumbing-reviews-7190213.htm" target="_blank">Angie's List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Content" -->
<div id="paragraph">
  <h1>Welcome to Source Plumbing</h1>
  <h2>Orange County's Leak Detection Experts</h2>
  <p>TEXT, TEXT, TEXT</p>
</div>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->

  <div id="footer">
    <p><img src="/images/footer-bar.png" alt="footer image"></p>
    <p>For more information <a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a> or call <a href="tel:1-949-632-5995">(949) 632-5995</a></p>
    <p><img src="/images/footer-bar.png" alt="footer image"></p>
    <p>&copy; 2014 All rights reserved. <a href="terms.html">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="/sitemap.html">Site Map</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="media-footer">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.sourceplumbing.com" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="bubble" data-width="300" data-href="http://www.sourceplumbing.com"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=true;e.src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js?onload=onLoadCallback";var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t)})()</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/*RESET*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; background:transparent;    } body {line-height: 1;    }ol, ul{list-style:none;    } blockquote, q{quotes:none;    } blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after{content:'';content:none;    } :focus{outline:0;    } ins{text-decoration:none;    } del{text-decoration:line-through;    } table{border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;    }
body {
    background-color:#7296d9;
}
#wrapper {
    width:auto;
    min-width:225px;
    min-height:1024px;
    background:url(../images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin:4px;
}
#content {
    width:98%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
}
#header {
    width:98%;
    max-height:30px;
    min-width:350px;
    position:relative;
}
#header #logo, #logo img {
    max-width:400px;
    min-width:200px;
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
#header #servingsince, #servingsince img {
    float:right;
    max-width:400px;
    min-width:230px;
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    margin: 8% auto auto auto;
}
#phone, #phone img {
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    right:2%;
    max-width:400px;
    min-width:120px;
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
}
#paragraph {
    width:80%;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#666;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:10px auto 25px auto;
}
p {
    margin:15px 0 15px 0;
}
h1 {
    line-height:48px;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
}
h2 {
    line-height:42px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
span.pointer {
    cursor:pointer;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#menu {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    float:left;
}
#menu ul {
    height:auto;
    font-size: 16px;;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: table-row;
    margin:10px;
}
#menu a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#menu a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
#menu ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}
#menu ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    width:auto;
    padding:10px;
}
#menu ul a:link, a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff;
}
#menu ul ul {
    background-color: rgba(153,153,153,.9);
    border-radius: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}
#menu ul ul:last-child, nav ul ul:last-child a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
#menu ul ul li a {
    text-align:left;
    color: #000;
}        
#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
#mediaicons {
    text-align:center;
}
#mediaicons img {
    margin:auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    width:5%;
    min-width:32px;
}
#reviews {
    width:80%;
    text-align:justify;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:25px auto 25px auto;
}
#reviews img {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}
#form-webmaster, #form-plumber, #form-webmaster p, #form-plumber p {
    display:block;
    color: #666;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:400px;
}
input[type=text], textarea {
    width:100%;
}
.bottombar {
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
#footer, #footer p {
    font-size:12px;
    color: #666;
    text-align:center;
    width:auto;
    margin:5px 0 5px 0;
}
#footer img {
    width:100%;
}
#media-footer, #media-footer img {
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0 15px 55px;
}
nav ul {
    display:none;
}
#minimenu {
    display:none;
}
.reviews {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:justify;
    color: #666;
}
#vcard-button {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#d5d5d5, #595959); /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #cccccc;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    color:    #000;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
#vcard-button a:link, a:visited{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#vcard-button a:hover, a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#vcard-button:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#vcard-div {
    width:350px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: what am I supposed to be looking at in those screenshots?

Comment: If you see the H1 tags, "Welcome to Source Plumbing" in FF, it starts at the top of the screen. Not below the menu.

Comment: In your example code, I see no `<h1>` tags. Also, [pasting your code](http://jsbin.com/EMuBIdoy/1/) to test what might be wrong doesn't show the problem. Could you please make sure you post the code of the part that is actually causing problems?

Comment: I just updated the code above. Realized I copied and pasted from the template. I removed two P tags, but that is really all the code that is missing from the HTML on the index file, and any other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your div structure to:

```
html
 wrapper
  header
    navigation titles logo`s etc,..
  /header
  content
    sidebars, contents
  /content
 footer
 /footer
/wrapper
/html
```

It makes youre HTML a bit better organized, and will probably solve your problem.
Change 1:
you set you background as reset to transparent. try it without this statement.
Change 2: 
Set before the Content div an clear:both. usually it is been done as so:

html:
*before*

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

*after*
Css:

```
.clear{clear:both}
```

Comment: I will give that a shot. Thank you for the suggestion. I will post back shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not fix it.

Comment: If you look at the page in FF [www.sourceplumbing.com](http://www.sourceplumbing.com) you can see how the H1 tag starts at the top of the page, above the menu. If you look at it in IE or Chrome, the H1 starts below the menu as it should.

Comment: Solved it, You must do an clear:both. do it so:  <div style="clear:both"></div> before the content div. it resets the margin and padding.

Comment: Solved it, you did! Thank you very much!!! Now, I am still new to StackOverflow... how do I mark a comment as the answer?

Comment: Not, you make the answer. i made an change in the answer so it competes with the story. :) hapy to see it worked!

Comment: Oh, I see you edited your post above. I will mark that. Thank you again, Bart!!